# number the rows for the same id

Tags: sql-server

I want to add a new column to my table, so I did:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD pixelorder int
```

now my table looks like:

```
id     |  name  | pixelorder
----------------------------
1525   |   a    |
1528   |   b    |
1525   |   w    |
1526   |   b    |
1526   |   v    |
1528   |   c    |
1525   |   b    |
```

I sorted the rows by id:

```
select * from myTable order by id asc

id     |  name  | pixelorder
----------------------------
1525   |   a    |
1525   |   w    |
1525   |   b    |
1526   |   b    |
1526   |   v    |
1528   |   b    |
1528   |   c    |
```

and now I want to count the rows for each id, while the first row of the same Id is starts with '1', the second is 2, etc).

so, for my example:

```
id     |  name  | pixelorder
----------------------------
1525   |   a    |    1
1525   |   w    |    2
1525   |   b    |    3
1526   |   b    |    1
1526   |   v    |    2
1528   |   b    |    1
1528   |   c    |    2
```

how can I do it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ROW_NUMBER` function can do that:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/974eb/2)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTable
    ([id] int, [name] varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO MyTable
    ([id], [name])
VALUES
    (1525, 'a'),
    (1528, 'b'),
    (1525, 'w'),
    (1526, 'b'),
    (1526, 'v'),
    (1528, 'c'),
    (1525, 'b')
;

------------------------------------

ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable ADD pixelorder int;

------------------------------------
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/974eb/2/0)**:

```
|   ID | NAME | PIXELORDER |
|------|------|------------|
| 1525 |    a |     (null) |
| 1528 |    b |     (null) |
| 1525 |    w |     (null) |
| 1526 |    b |     (null) |
| 1526 |    v |     (null) |
| 1528 |    c |     (null) |
| 1525 |    b |     (null) |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name) AS rn
FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/974eb/2/1)**:

```
|   ID | NAME | PIXELORDER | RN |
|------|------|------------|----|
| 1525 |    a |     (null) |  1 |
| 1525 |    b |     (null) |  2 |
| 1525 |    w |     (null) |  3 |
| 1526 |    b |     (null) |  1 |
| 1526 |    v |     (null) |  2 |
| 1528 |    b |     (null) |  1 |
| 1528 |    c |     (null) |  2 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
UPDATE t
  SET pixelorder = rn
FROM (
  SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name) AS rn
  FROM dbo.MyTable
  )t;


SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/974eb/2/2)**:

```
|   ID | NAME | PIXELORDER |
|------|------|------------|
| 1525 |    a |          1 |
| 1528 |    b |          1 |
| 1525 |    w |          3 |
| 1526 |    b |          1 |
| 1526 |    v |          2 |
| 1528 |    c |          2 |
| 1525 |    b |          2 |
```

Query 2 shows how to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function in a `SELECT` query. Query3 shows how to use it in an update statement.

The `ROW_NUMBER()`'s `OVER()` clause has two parts. The `PARTITION BY` bart tells SQL Server to reset the counter back to 1 for every `id` value. The `ORDER BY` part allows to specify the order in which the rows are counted within each partition.

Answer (score 1):

`ROW_NUMBER()` is a ranking function which generates sequential number. The generation of number was done inside a recursive CTE so we can be able to update the `pixelorder`. However, this can also be done using subquery.

```
WITH records
AS
(
    SELECT  id, name, pixelorder,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY name) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
UPDATE records 
SET pixelOrder = rn
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/30584/2)